# How to print uc-auction-bid-table-form seperately in product node template using ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am trying to print uc-auction bid table separately in product node template. I have printed the add-to-cart button separately like this in the node--product.tpl.php.

```
<?php 
 print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'.$node->nid, $node));
?>
```

Similarly how can i print uc_auction form(uc-auction-bid-table-form) separately. I can't able to print like above for uc-auction because it doesn't have any nids associated it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what happens if you try to simply replicate your older solution and modify it for new problem?

Comment: please edit your question when providing codes :)

Comment: Just a comment here. I strongly recommend that you do not user `drupal_get_form` in the theme layer. It will have an impact on your site performance.

Comment: @arsenelupin: Then how do i print separately the add-to-cart form and uc-acution form. any suggestions?

Comment: In a module use hook_node_load to add proper elements to the node object and hook_node_view to render the output. Look at the comment module and how it does it; namely comment_node_load and comment_node_view.

Answer (score 0):

In your module which implements hook_node_view, to accomplish this, do something along these lines:

```
   function module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
      // Do business logic here like if these node should have the form then...
      $node->content['your_from'] = array(
        '#markup' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('uc_auction_bid_table_form')),
        '#weight' => 10,
        // you may or may not need this based on your implementation : '#theme' => 'theme_uc_auction_bid_table',
      );
    }
```

Drupal 6: use hook_nodeapi

```
function modulename_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {   
    case 'view':
      // Do business logic here like if these node should have the form then...
      $node->content['uc_auction_bid_table'] = array(
        // Try drupal_render if theme does not work            
       '#value' => theme('uc_auction_bid_table', drupal_get_form('uc_auction_bid_table_form')),
        '#weight' => 10,
      );
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm also looking for option to render this form in block (in product node page). Is it possible? Have u tried anything like that?